# how to make directives communicate with each other but also reusable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a simple feature that lets you add a user to a table. You fill out a form and click submit to add the user to the table.

There are three views and each view has a directive.  The views are:

1) A panel (wrapper which controls which view to present) 2) A form view (panel body) 3) A table view (panel body)
**All have isolated scope**. **I want to make these directives reusable (hence, the isolated scope)**

Looks like this:

```
<main-user-directive>
 <user-table  ng-show = "viewMode === 'table'"></user-table>
 <add-user-form  ng-show = "viewMode === 'addForm'"></add-user-form>  
</main-user-directive>
```

Right now, if you try to add a user, but cancel the process without completing, `<add-user-form>` needs to require `<main-user-directive>`'s controller to access the `$scope.cancelForm` function (which basically changes `$scope.viewMode` form `'addForm'` to `'table'`).

I'm not sure this makes my  directive very reusable. 
**So my question is:** should I require the controller of the parent directive or use something like a service to control which view to present? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use isolate scope "&"

```
<main-user-directive>
 <user-table  ng-show="viewMode === 'table'"></user-table>
 <add-user-form  ng-show="viewMode === 'addForm'" on-cancel="cancelForm()"></add-user-form>  
</main-user-directive>
```

In your directive

```
scope: {
  onCancel: '&'
},
template: "<button ng-click='onCancel()'>Cancel</button>"
```

Check out this short video: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/HIcFdOANNertcLNQTSqI?p=preview